# HttpClient and Connection Timeout

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I send http requests over Apache HttpClient and my code is here:

```
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("78.1.1.222", 80);

    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
    httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
        .build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + encoding);
        httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        responseCode=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        ........
        ........(code continue..)
```

My question is that how can I add connection timeout time to this code?
Note that I must use proxy with that and I use HttpClient 4.4 .

Comment: Have you checked the Apache HttpClient documentation? Does it have a suitable method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout explains various ways to set the connection timeout.